# Difference between two type of assignments in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Both assignment are different. Is there any difference between both of them or both are equal?

**First**

```
onClick(){
  return (
     <div></div>
  )
}
```

**Second**

```
const onClick= ()=> {
   return(
       <div></div>
   )
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable)

Comment: My question is somehow related to this but not the all. What is the difference in rendering from a arrow function and a function?

Comment: There is a typo in your first code `onClick(){` should be `function onClick(){`

Comment: No, it's identical. You might only be interested in what happens when the function returns JSX (which is compiled to regular Javascript objects anyway), but the differences between doing so in an arrow function or "regular" function are still exactly those defined by the language specification. Which is exactly what's covered in the duplicates. In short: in the toy example you give, there is no difference. But there may be if you use `this` inside the function, or in other rare cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function or fat arrow for a React functional component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54331084/function-or-fat-arrow-for-a-react-functional-component)

Comment: i think when we add function to the statement then it will be equivalent to the second type.

Answer (score 5):

**ES5 Functions**

This type of function doesn't bind with the current context you need to bind it manually, if we do not bind the function with `this` then the function will find its binding by itself while executing the function according to the execution context.

```
this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
```

```
onClick() {
  return <div></div>;
}
```

**ES6 Functions**

Simply known as arrow functions, in arrow function there is no binding of `this` so no effect of `this` keyword according to the execution context

```
onClick = () => {
  return <div></div>;
}
```

**How Execution Context Effect?**

Es5 function behave differently when executed if the function is bounded with any other instance(object) then the `this` refer to that instance if there is no binding then the `this` keyword refers to its parent scope.

The setTimeout executed in the global execution context the callback function `es5Function` which is not bound to any instance, the `this` keyword in the function will refer to its parent scope which is in our case `window`

```html
<script>
  window.name = "Global Scope";

  function App() {
    this.name = "App Scope";

    let es5Function = function () {
      console.log("I am Es5 function I am in the " + this.name);
    };

    let es5FunctionWithBinding = function () {

      console.log(
        "I am Es5 function binded with THIS, I am in the " + this.name
      );

    }.bind(this);

    let es6Function = () => {
      console.log("I am Es6 function I am in the " + this.name);
    };

    return [es5Function, es5FunctionWithBinding, es6Function];
  }

  const [es5Function, es5FunctionWithBinding, es6Function] = new App();

  setTimeout(es5Function, 1000);
  setTimeout(es5FunctionWithBinding, 1000);
  setTimeout(es6Function, 1000);

</script>
```

**Using as Function Constructor**

One more simple difference is we can not use arrow functions as a function constructor

**The question is why?**

When we create an object using function constructor (with `new` keyword) then the function returns the `this` keyword by default which refers to a new memory location every time.

So simple conclusion

- Es5 function has it's own `this` when using it with `new` keyword so it returns it by default
- Es6 arrow function throw an error `[function name] is not a constructor` ( because arrow function doesn’t has its own `this`)

```html
<script>
  function Es5(name) {
    this.name = name;
    // by default it will return this when using with `new` keyword
  }

  const Es6 = (name) => {
    this.name = name; // here this refers to global scope which is window
  };

  let es5Instance = new Es5("MUHAMMAD ILYAS");
  console.log("Es5 instance => Name:", es5Instance.name);

  try {
    let es6Instance = new Es6("jsfit");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Es6 with new keyword => ERROR:", e.message);
  }

  let es6InstanceWithoutNewKeyword = Es6("jsfit");
  // es6InstanceWithoutNewKeyword will be Undefined because nothing was returned from Es6 function
  console.log("ES6 without new keyword: ", es6InstanceWithoutNewKeyword);

  // I am in the global scope so here `this` refers to `window` so both will result the `name` exactly the same

  console.log("Global scope: ", this.name, "or", window.name);
</script>
```

Comment: But you dont always need to bound context, very rarely... If you're going to have a lot of instances of this component on your page - better use normal function as it will not be created for each instrance - it will remain in prototype. Arrow functions will be created for each instance which will unnecesserily consume memory

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference in rendering from a arrow function and a
>   function?

There is no difference at all.

Arrow functions differ from regular functions in how they handle `this`. There are other differences as well but difference related to handling of `this` is the most significant one.

Not related to your question but you should know that first `onClick` function cannot be used inside functional components unless `function` keyword is written before the function name and second `onClick` function cannot be used inside class components unless `const` keyword is removed.

Answer (score -1):

Difference is **You can change the elements of a constant but you cannot reassign the constant**

Comment: Please elaborate this. I cannot understand this :)

Comment: const onClick= ()=> {
   return(
       <div></div>
   )
 }-----Not possible to  add another onclick if its declared as const

Comment: i got it. But can you please explain this from the aspect of rendering.